# Fill UIPickerView with an Array Value

Tags: iphone, ipad

i am working on a project in which i have to perform following two work:
1.) Fetch value from *CoreData* and store it in an *NSMutableArray*.
2.) Take a *UIPickerView* and fill it with an Array value.

Problem is that size of array is dynamic and i canto fill an array value in *UIPickerView*. can someone help me.

Comment: What is `UIPickercontroller` ?

Comment: What you have tried till now? You are using UIPickerView? Did you implement the delegate methods for it?

Comment: @jhaliya UIPickercontroller is use to show  an array value.

@Terente Yes i have Implemented it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in order for the UIPickerView to work correctly, you must supply the amount of components (columns) and the number of rows for each component whenever it reloads:
as mentioned, use `[myPickerView  reloadAllComponents];` to reload the view once the array is populated, but you MUST implement also these things after you declare the containing view controller class as `<UIPickerViewDelegate>` link the picker to the file owner as a delegate, and then:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
   return 1;// or the number of vertical "columns" the picker will show...
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (myLoadedArray!=nil) {
        return [myLoadedArray count];//this will tell the picker how many rows it has - in this case, the size of your loaded array...
    }
    return 0;
}

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
//you can also write code here to descide what data to return depending on the component ("column")
        if (myLoadedArray!=nil) {
            return [myLoadedArray objectAtIndex:row];//assuming the array contains strings..
        }
        return @"";//or nil, depending how protective you are
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget about `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol

Answer (score 1):

After updating the value (Inserting or modifying existing) in your array.

Call `reloadAllComponents` on your `UIPickerView` instance.

```
- (void)reloadAllComponents
```

Use as below

```
[myPickerView  reloadAllComponents];
```